# Magento admin screens add new review button not working and generates a 404 error

Tags: php, magento, http-status-code-404, admin, review

Magento Enterprise Edition, version 1.13.1.0

Unable to add a new product review via admin screens. When "Add new Review" button is clicked in Admin, menu Catalog : Reviews and Ratings : Customer Reviews : All Reviews, and exception is generated in Magento and the 404 page is then shown.

This is a clean Magento installation, with no customisations.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The block class app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Review/Rating/Detailed.php, at line 74 calls the setStoreFilter(), using a hard-coded store code "default", which generates an exception when there are no stores in Magento with code "default", and when error pages are switched off, forwards the admin user to 404 page.

To reproduce the problem, create a second store and related store view in Magento, change the "default" store code to "mystorecode", then go to Admin menu "Catalog > Reviews and Ratings > Customer Reviews > All Reviews" and press the "Add New Review" button.

The proposed fix is the following:

```
--- a/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Review/Rating/Detailed.php
+++ b/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Review/Rating/Detailed.php
@@ -68,10 +68,13 @@ class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Review_Rating_Detailed extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_T
                     ->addRatingOptions();

             } elseif (!$this->getIsIndependentMode()) {
+                $default_store = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getDefaultStore();
                 $ratingCollection = Mage::getModel('rating/rating')
                     ->getResourceCollection()
                     ->addEntityFilter('product')
-                    ->setStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId())
+                    ->setStoreFilter( ($default_store) 
+                                      ? $default_store->getId() 
+                                      : Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID )
                     ->setPositionOrder()
                     ->load()
                     ->addOptionToItems();
```

simply replace:

```
                 $ratingCollection = Mage::getModel('rating/rating')
                     ->getResourceCollection()
                     ->addEntityFilter('product')
                     ->setStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId())
                     ->setPositionOrder()
                     ->load()
                     ->addOptionToItems();
```

with:

```
                 $default_store = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getDefaultStore();
                 $ratingCollection = Mage::getModel('rating/rating')
                     ->getResourceCollection()
                     ->addEntityFilter('product')
                     ->setStoreFilter( ($default_store) 
                                       ? $default_store->getId() 
                                       : Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID )
                     ->setPositionOrder()
                     ->load()
                     ->addOptionToItems();
```

Hope this solves the problem.

Comment: So do i have to set my default store code always to "default" ?

Comment: When i am trying to save a new review nothing comes up! Maybe it needs more fixing?

Comment: You don't have to set your store code to "default", this is exactly what the fix is intended for.

Comment: If the reviews are not stored, but you don't have the symptoms described in this post (no 404 page or exceptions reported and you're actually able to submit the review via front-end), the fix has worked, but there are other issues in your installation. Do you see the review you have submitted in Magento admin screens? It may require approval before it can be shown in front-end. This is a feature configurable in admin (System > Configuration).

Comment: Yes when adding a review in the front-end it works fine. After the fix the back-end doesn't get the 404 error but when adding a new review it reports "review was saved" but nothing comes up. About the code part now, I asked you if the Magento team suggests developers to keep the "default" code for the default store or its fine to use another one? I am asking this because i am facing a similer problem with the extension [MageMonkey](http://tinyurl.com/o7o4lh5) where the auto generated emails to customers have no image showing. Is this [this](http://tinyurl.com/nzxhy29) related?

Comment: Just a note - I saw this problem also in Magento CE 1.9.x.x the fix above resolves the problem.

Comment: a further note, this seems to be resolved in CE 1.9.2.0 with ->setStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getDefaultStoreView()->getId())

Answer (score 1):

that Magento team fix this issue in the newer version , they add this code

```
->setStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getDefaultStoreView()->getId())
```

instead of

```
->setStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId())
```

i think the best idea  to upgrade the version